# Toggle CSS class in Polymer 1.0 template?

Tags: javascript, html, css, polymer, polymer-1.0

What is most correct way to toggle CSS class of element in Polymer 1.0 template depending on boolean condition?

```
<style>
    .employee{
        ...
    }
    .employee-selected{
        ...
    }
</style>
<template is="{{dom-repeat}}" items="{{employees}}">

  <template is="{{dom-if}}" if="{{!item.isSelected}}"> 
    <div class="employe">{{item.name}}</div>
  </template>

  <template is="{{dom-if}}" if="{{item.isSelected}}">
    <div class="employee employee-selected">{{item.name}}</div>
  </template>

</template>
```

Is there better way to do this in Polymer 1.0?

(without using css class name in JavaScript)

Maybe like this?

```
<style>
    .employee{
        ...
    }
    .employee[data-selected]{
        ...
    }
</style>
<template is="{{dom-repeat}}" items="{{employees}}">
    <div class="employee" 
         data-selected$="{{item.isSelected}}">{{item.name}}</div>
</template>
```

Comment: I am just starting with polymer, but you can make use of a function or computedProperty. Or keep what you have and use an attribute selector in the CSS.

Comment: epascarello, thank you for answer, but I don't want to use a functions, because I want split work between JavaScript developer (who will create polymer component JS part) and HTML designer (who will create polymer template). If JS part will "know" about CSS classes and GUI logic, then JS developer should coordinate this with HTML designer.

Comment: A computed property is nothing more than doing `class$="[[employeeClass]]"` and the JS developer would just need to return the classes...Seems weird they can not communicate that to each other.

Comment: Of course they can communicate :) But this will violate MVC pattern and create excess cohesion between JS logic and GUI

Comment: So use CSS with the data attribute and specify the value `.employee[data-selected="true"]`. In 0.5 it would have been possible to do it with the `|` operator, but that was removed for the computed stuff.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're on the right track with that attribute selector, however the `data-` prefix is not necessary and may unexpectedly interact with the HTML5 data attributes system.  You can get away with just `selected`:

```
<style>
    .employee{
        ...
    }
    .employee[selected]{
        ...
    }
</style>
<template is="dom-repeat" items="[[employees]]">
    <div class="employee" 
         selected$="{{item.isSelected}}">[[item.name]]</div>
</template>
```

Alternatively, if you really want to use classes:

```
<style>
    .employee{
        ...
    }
    .employee.selected{
        ...
    }
</style>
<template is="dom-repeat" items="[[employees]]">
    <div class$="{{_computeEmployeeSelected(item)}}">[[item.name]]</div>
</template>
<script>
  Polymer({
    _computeEmployeeSelected: function(item) {
      return 'employee '+(item.isSelected ? 'selected' : '');
    }
  });
</script>
```

Comment: Okay-okay, but what I must do in situation when I use third-party CSS bootstrap, and I want to apply CSS class from that bootstrap on the selected employee element? Maybe there some feature in Polymer 1.0, like CSS mixin in LESS?

Comment: I've included an example that uses computed bindings.  Note that I do not know how this will interact with shadow DOM polyfills, which can depend on various classes they apply automatically.